# Unable to make Stacked Bar chart data labels left and right aligned

Tags: highcharts, stacked-bar-chart

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBlPZ.png)
I have below highcharts script and trying to make the data labels to left, middle and right aligned inside the bar. If you see in my script below, *wanted to have data labels: 30% to be left aligned, 50% in center aligned which is working and taking it as by default, 20% to be right aligned*. But it not working for me and showing data labels as center aligned for all three. Also, tried to change from inline <span> tag to block level tags: <div> . Its not working for me.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>    
</figure>
```

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
colors:['#006fcf','#00175A','#808080'],
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        zoomType:'xy',
        alignTicks:false,
        width:170,
        height:35,
        marginBottom:0,
        marginLeft:0,
        marginRight:0,
        marginTop:0,
        spaceBottom:0,
        spaceLeft:0,
        spaceRight:0,
        spaceTop:0,
        shadow:false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    exporting : {
      enabled:false
    },    
    yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        stacklabels: {
            useHTML: true
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
      enabled:false,
      href:"",
      text:""
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          stacking:'percent',
          dataLabels: {
              enabled:true,
              style: {
                 textOutline: 'none'
              },
              formatter: function() {
              
                   var alignText = (this.colorIndex == 0) ? 'left' : ((this.colorIndex == 1) ? 'center':'right');
                   return '<span style ="font-family:BentonSans Medium; font-weight:400; font-size: 9px; textAlign:'+alignText+'">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage,0) +'% </span>';
              }
          }
        },
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: false,
            lineWidth:2,
            overlapWidth:'3px',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                y:-2.3
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'EV',
        data: [20]
    }, {
        name: 'GAS',
        data: [50]
    }, {
        name: 'HYBRID',
        data: [30]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align each dataLabel on a different side, you need to set it for each series or point separately:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'EV',
    dataLabels: {
      align: 'right',
    },
    data: [20],
  }, {
    name: 'GAS',
    dataLabels: {
      align: 'center',
    },
    data: [50],
  }, {
    name: 'HYBRID',
    dataLabels: {
      align: 'left',
    },
    data: [30],
  }]
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lwrxet2c/